# How to turn my 10 inch tablet into primary PC touch monitor (Windows 7)?

Tags: android, external-display, tablet

How to turn my 10 inch tablet into primary PC touch monitor (Windows 7) ?

There is alike question 
[How would you turn a tablet into a keyboard + easy-to-reach touchscreen (mirror the desktop) (not a touchpad) for a desktop PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/564421/how-would-you-turn-a-tablet-into-a-keyboard-easy-to-reach-touchscreen-mirror)

suggesting VNC server.

All I need is to have 10 inch Android tablet installed in my car as touch monitor and have GUI, camera view processing done by a more powerful laptop or PC installed in the same car.

Since PC is heavy and consumes high power I would prefer Windows 7 tablet for tests.

There is a number of tablet as a secondary monitor solutions on the Internet but I need to use 10" tablet as a Primary Control Monitor for Windows 7 since I need touch screen functionality to access GUI menu (Chrome)

thank you
darius

Comment: no comments at all ?